# Craftbukkit Player Count Message Plugin Coding Error

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, bukkit

I am making a Craftbukkit plugin that has a message in the player count list, Like HIVEmc or Omega Realm.   I am coding  in Ecplise and using ProtocolLib v3.2.0 and Craftbukkit 1.7.2 R0.3.  I am new to java and don't understand it much.    SO FAR... Here is my code and the error

```
    public void onEnable() {
    saveConfig();
    if(!new File(getDataFolder(),"RESET.FILE").exists()){
        try {
            getConfig().set("Message",
                    Arrays.asList("First Line","Second Line"));
            new File(getDataFolder(),"RESET.FILE").createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }   
}
```

ERROR: The method asList(T[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)
http://tinypic.com/r/n6yond/8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
Arrays.asList(new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"}));
```